# Relative Path for VueJS / Laravel does not work when accessing a specific nested page (Router History On)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So here's my question. I have a site blog site called www.blog.com which is the root URL.
I link my images like this.

Basically for root URL 
URL: `www.blog.com` 
Resource Path :  `public/img/blog-logo.png` `<img :src="public/img/blog-logo.png">`

and for nested routes
URL: `www.blog.com/blog/i-am-a-post` 
Resource Path :  `public/img/blog-logo.png`. `<img :src="public/img/blog-logo.png">`

Which is fairly the same. and if I go to the main  `www.blog.com` and navigate to `www.blog.com/blog/i-am-a-post`I am able to see the images okay. However, when I access directly `www.blog.com/blog/i-am-a-post` (i.e typing the URL) in the browser, my image path looks like this `www.blog.com/blog/i-am-a-post/public/blog-logo.png`. So my question how do you configure or handle image paths? When a user directly access a page?

I already have a solution for it by creating an image helper method i.e `v-bind:src="assetURL + 'public/img/blog-logo.png'"` where `assetURL` is dynamic in creating `'../'`depending on how nested the URL path is. But I want to know how you guys implement such a way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using laravel+vue using laravel.mix? You can just call `/img/blog-logo.png` where img folder is inside your public folder.